# Java Regex Match Error

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying the following segment to no avail:

```
 public class test {

    public static void main(String args[] ){

       String password = "s8bgBQYPmUaNjkToXCJLAwAA";
       System.out.println( Pattern.matches("[0-9]", password ));

   }
```

}

I would expect that to work since I'm just looking for match of any digit to suffice the regex but my output always comes back false. Any help as to what I maybe missing or what could be wrong would be most appreciated.

Comment: Just in case you want a regex to make sure that the password contains at least one digit, one letter and has a minimum length of 10, `"^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{10,}$"` Check out look-around for more info http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking whether the whole string consists of one single digit. What you really mean is:

```
System.out.println( Pattern.matches(".*[0-9].*", password ));
```

Adding the `.*` to the start and end lets it match any number of other characters (`.` means "any character" and `*` means "any number of times").

Answer (score 0):

you may or may not want to use [A-z] instead of . if you don't want it to match special characters.  I'm not a java guy, so the specifics of regex in java are best presented by: http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Comment: Did you really mean to write `[A-z]` (capital `A`, lowercase `z`)?  That's almost certainly an error, no matter what regex flavor you're working with.  And who are you talking to, anyway?  I suspect this should have been posted as a comment on @mmyers' answer, not as an answer in its own right.

Comment: agreed, apologies for not just commenting.  Yes, i mean to cap the Z.

Comment: This answer was helpful to me as it was with [A-z], not [A-Z]. It turns out that there are several characters, including underscore "_" between upper case Z and lower case a in ASCII, and those get matched with [A-z] in Java -- which was a bug in my code. Therefore the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this type of character interrogation often in a loop, you may not want to use a regexp at all but craft your own search routine interrogating a StringBuffer.

```
/**
* Method to evaluate a String to see whether it contains one (or potentially more) of a 
* char or member of a group of chars.
*
* @param String to evaluate
*
* @param String containing all characters to evaluate against the subject string
*
* @return true on first correct match, false if no match found
**/

public boolean sbContainsOneOf(String sStringToCheck, String sCheck)
{
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(sStringToCheck);

char[] tmp2 = sCheck.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++)
    {

    for (int k = 0; k < tmp2.length; k++)
    if (sb.charAt(i) == tmp2[k])
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
return false;
}
```

Then all you need to do is call it:

```
String password = "s8bgBQYPmUaNjkToXCJLAwAA"; 
System.out.println(sbContainsOneOf(password,"0123456789"));
```

It's between 10 and 15 times faster doing it this way.... The longer your String & option list the bigger the difference between the two becomes. Generally I avoid regexps unless they're one offs or spectacularly complex to implement as code and prefer to rep them with optimised StringBuffer-based routines. Doing it this way, gradually your collection of regexp replacements fills up and you end up with a very useable way of pattern interrogation without the high associated regexp overheads.