# Java regex basic usage problem

Tags: java, regex

The following code works:

```
String str= "test with foo hoo";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("foo");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

if(matcher.find()) { ... }
```

But this example does not:

```
if(Pattern.matches("foo", str)) { ... }
```

And neither this version:

```
if(str.matches("foo")) { ... }
```

In the real code, str is a chunk of text with multiple lines if that is treated differently by the matcher, also in the real code, replace will be used to replace a string of text.

Anyway, it is strange that it works in the first version but not the other two versions.

**Edit**

Ok, I realise that the behaviour is the same in the first example if `if(matcher.matches()) { ... }` is used instead of `matcher.find`. I still cannot make it work for multiline input but I stick to the `Pattern.compile`/`Pattern.matcher` solution anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last couple of examples fail because `matches` adds an implicit start and end anchor to your regular expression. In other words, it must be an exact match of the entire string, not a partial match.

You can work around this by using `.*foo.*` instead. Using `Matcher.find` is more flexible solution though, so I'd recommend sticking with that.

Comment: Ok .*//.* solves the single line example, but how do you extend it to multi line input?

Comment: @Ernelli: You could use DOTALL mode. `Dotall mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression (?s)`

Answer (score 1):

In Java, [`String.matches`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) delegates to [`Pattern.matches`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) which in turn delegates to [`Matcher.matches`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29), which checks if a regex **matches the entire string**.

From the [`java.util.regex.Matcher` API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

> Once created, a matcher can be used to perform three different kinds of match operations:
>
> - The `matches` method attempts to match the **entire input sequence** against the pattern.
> - The `lookingAt` method attempts to match the input sequence, starting at the beginning, against the pattern.
> - The `find` method scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern.

To find if a substring matches *pattern*, you can:

- `Matcher.find()` the `pattern` within the string
- Check if the entire string `matches` `.*pattern.*`

#### Related questions

On `matches()` matching *whole* string:

- [Why is my regex is not matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314568/why-is-my-regex-is-not-matching)
- [Java Regex Match Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211788/java-regex-match-error)
- [Java RegEx Pattern not matching (works in .NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724222/java-regex-pattern-not-matching-works-in-net)

On `hitEnd()` for partial matching:

- [How can I perform a partial match with `java.util.regex.*`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469231/how-can-i-perform-a-partial-match-with-java-util-regex)
- [Can `java.util.regex.Pattern` do partial matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526756/can-java-util-regex-pattern-do-partial-matches)

On multiline vs singleline/`Pattern.DOTALL` mode:

- [`string.matches(".*")` returns `false`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396834/string-matches-returns-false)